# libfastcgipp < error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, fastcgi++

Pretty new to c++, coded a few years in other languages though.
I been stuck all day with this issue that I can't seem to figure out.

When I run the code published here: http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/doc/2.1/a00004.html
I get the following error message:

> error while loading shared libraries: libfastcgipp.so.2: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory

Using `ubuntu 13.10`

I can build the code with out problem, but not run it. There is a `libfastcgipp.so.2` and `libfastcgipp.so` in `/usr/local/lib/`

I tryed creating a symlink from `/usr/lib/libfastcgipp.so`

---

### edit

Result from ldd command...

```
ldd joppli.bot.dummy 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff497fe000)
    libboost_system.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f8b1828f000)
    libboost_thread.so.1.53.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.53.0 (0x00007f8b18079000)
    libfastcgipp.so.2 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8b17d74000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8b17b5e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8b17795000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8b1758d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8b17370000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8b1706b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8b184b6000)
```

Comment: try to run `ldd <you-binary-program>`

Comment: Likely you've built the binary on one computer/operating system and now try to run on another.

Comment: @user3159253 Updated question, No I build and run it on the same computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a symlink to the file as first explained above, but added the trailing number `2`, the version number, at the end.

e.g: `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libfastcgipp.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/libfastcgipp.so.2`

---

#### UPDATE

Ran in to this issue again and couldn't figure out the same issue again, so I'm posting a docker file that will get your fastCGI++ script running (probably only me that will use this, but anyway ...)

The fastcgi++2.1 source: http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgipp/

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Stockholm /etc/localtime \
  && echo "Europe/Stockholm" > /etc/timezone

ENV TERM xterm

RUN echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install \
  build-essential \
  libboost-all-dev \
  git \
  apache2 \
  libapache2-mod-fastcgi

COPY dependencies/fastcgi++-2.1.tar.bz2 /tmp/fastcgi++-2.1.tar.bz2

RUN cd /tmp \
  && tar xvf fastcgi++-2.1.tar.bz2 \
  && cd fastcgi++-2.1 \
  && ./configure \
  && make \
  && make install

RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/libfastcgipp.so.2.0.0 /usr/lib/libfastcgipp.so.2

COPY rep /tmp/app

RUN cd /tmp/app \
  && g++ main.cpp -o example -std=gnu++11 -lfastcgipp -lboost_system -lboost_thread \
  && mv example /var/www/example

COPY config/apache/default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf
COPY config/apache/.htaccess /var/www/.htaccess
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/log/apache/
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2dissite 000-default
RUN a2ensite example.conf
RUN service apache2 restart

RUN apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean all

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

---

**config/apache/default.conf**

```
ServerName example

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    SetHandler fastcgi-script

    <Directory "/var/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /tmp/log/apache/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /tmp/log/apache/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ example [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex example
```